# Cannot access object properties in Tracker.autorun()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am unable to access object properties in a `Tracker.autorun()`. I can `console.log()` the object but cannot do `object.id` or `object[id]` or `object["id"]`. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Here's my code:

`Tracker.autorun(function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      Me = FacebookCollections.getCollection("/me/accounts");
    }
});`

`Tracker.autorun(function() {
    if (Meteor.user() && Me) {
      Account = Me.find().fetch()[0];
      console.log(Account);    // this works
      console.log(Account.id); // this doesn't
    } 
});`

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: a possible typo, should be `Account._id`?

Comment: Nope. It's Account.id. Gotten it to work by checking with `if(Account)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line ´Account = Me.find().fetch()[0];´, you're assuming that your query is returning at  least 1 item, you should always check before trying to access the "maybe it exists object". In your case this might no be the issue but remember to check the object: `if(Account){//your code}`

As Slava pointed, it's likely that your error is a typo @ `console.log(Account.id); // this doesn't`

Comment: I want to do another API call with the `Account.id` but I keep getting this error; `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. While I'm able to do `if (Account) console.log(Account.id)`, I can't do `if (Account) Posts = FacebookCollections.getCollection("/" + Account.id + "feed");`. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: `Account` might be an object but it might no have the `id` property and this will throw an error.

Comment: `Account` has an `id` property. I'm even able to display the contents of the Account object in my template but I'm unable to use its `id` property to make another API call.